# SImple code runs correctly in DevC++ but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++

Code runs fine DevC++ but not Visual Studio Code

Was doing a homework question. Simple code adding two integers. Code looked fine but running it kept giving me the wrong result. After losing my mind I tried to run it in DevC++ to which it gave me the result I expected.

I'm very very new to coding. Visual Studio Code is trying to tell me something in the output window but I don't know what it's is trying to tell me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x,y,z;

    printf("Enter first number:" );

    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("Enter second number:" );

    scanf("%i", &y);


    printf("the first number is: %d \n",x);
    printf("the second number is: %d \n ",y);


    z= x+y;

    printf("Output 1: The result is %d . \n",z);
    printf("Output 2: The sum of %d and %d is %d . ",x,y,z);

    return 0;
}
```

-------------------VS Code output Window-------------------------

```
hwidk.cpp:19:8: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
 printf("Output 1: The result is %d . \n",z);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~

[hwidk.cpp 2019-05-27 21:35:01.608]
hwidk.cpp:20:8: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
 printf("Output 2: The sum of %d and %d is %d . ",x,y,z);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
hwidk.cpp:20:8: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]

[hwidk.cpp 2019-05-27 21:35:01.608]
hwidk.cpp:20:8: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
```

--------------Visual Studio Runs the code as------------------------

```
Enter first number:5
Enter second number:6
the first number is: 5
the second number is: 6
Output 1: The result is 7 .
Output 2: The sum of 5 and 0 is 6
```

Comment: You need `int x,y,z;` as it's said in the error message

Comment: Your question gives examples for Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio, but none for DevC++ and makes no other mention of Visual Studio. Typo?

Comment: A Note on warnings: You don't always get warnings. Usually there is no Standard-mandated requirement for you to be warned about anything. Warnings are a little bone the compiler developers decide to throw you to tell you that your code, while syntactically correct and compiles, is probably logically wrong. Heed the warning and resolve it. Resolution may be as simple as, "Yep. I want it to do that." but usually you should offer the compiler a drink for saving you a buttload of debugging time.

Comment: Although this code can be compiled with a c++ compiler it's rather c code and you should tag it with c and not c++. In c++ you would solve this in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

The format strings you're using for your `scanf` and `printf` calls are wrong.  Since your variables are doubles, you should use `%f`.  `%d` is for integers.

Visual Studio performs some analysis of `printf` parameters when it can, and is warning you of the problem.  DevC++ apparently isn't doing this, so it doesn't generate the warnings.

The behavior is Undefined with either compiler, and you're unlucky enough that appears to work with DevC++.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually changed to %lf and it compiled and ran just fine. I  could also change from double to int, that also worked. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler that DevC++ uses is different than the one that you use with VS Code, mainly the problem is in the `printf`. You're using `%d`, which means an `integer` argument, but you're passing a `double` to it. DevC++ compiler might automatically truncate the double value to an integer value. Switching it to %f should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I made the changes you suggest and here is the result. `Enter first number:5
Enter second number:5
the first number is: 0.000000
the second number is: 0.000000
 Output 1: The result is 0.000000 .
Output 2: The sum of 0.000000 and 0.000000 is 0.000000 .`

Comment: Actually to store doubles you have to change `%i` to `%lf` as well